# Greedy optional character in regex

Tags: regex

I have two questions.

1. How to make optional character greedy? I'm trying to write custom
   parser and want that function arguments were in parentheses. For
   example `sin x` becomes `sin(x)` and `cosh^2 x` becomes `cosh^2(x)`. My
   regex:

   ```
   input = 'sinh x'
   output=re.sub(r'(sin|cos|tan|cot|sec|csc)(h?)\s*(|\^\s*[\(]?\s*\-?\s*\d+\s*[\)]?\s*)?([a-z0-9]+)',r'\1\2\3(\4)', input)
   ```

   This works fine. But when I input `sinh(x)`
   (already good-formed expression), it outputs `sin(h)(x)`. I need to
   make (h?) greedy or fail if there is no match in \4. How to do that? Note, that I can't write `([a-gi-z0-9])`,because `sinh(h)` is valid.
2. Is there any difference between `(h?)` and `([h]?)` ?

Comment: There's no difference between the RE `[single-character]` and `single-character`. The quantifier and capture group don't affect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Optional characters are already greedy (you would use `??` to make it non-greedy). But greediness just means that it will try to find the longest match that still allows the rest of the regular expression to match. It will still backtrack if necessary. If you want to force failure if there's something following it, one way to do that is with a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). I'm posting this for the value of the explanation above. Here's a regexp that uses this:

   ```
   (sin|cos|tan|cot|sec|csc)(?!.\([^)]*\))(h?)\s*(|\^\s*[\(]?\s*\-?\s*\d+\s*[\)]?\s*)?([a-z0-9]+)
   ```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zX1yI3/2)

2. A character class with a single character in it is identical to just putting that character into the RE directly. Quantifiers after it and capture groups around it don't make any difference. Sometimes single-character classes are useful as an alternative to escaping, e.g. `[*]?` may be easier to read than `\*?`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than making the optional `h` greedy, consider disambibuating your grammar by requiring that the letter inside parentheses be prefixed by a space or an opening parenthesis:

```
  ((?<=\s|\()[a-z0-9]+)
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This lookbehind ensures that `'h'` (or any other letter, for that matter) that follows the name of the function without spaces is *not* treated as a function parameter.

I would change the overall expression as follows:

```
((?:sin|cos|tan|cot|sec|csc)(?:h)?)\s*(?:[\^](\d+)\s*)?(?:((?<=\s|\()[a-z0-9]+)|[(]((?<=\s|\()[a-z0-9]+)[)])
```

to add an optional digit after `^`, and to make sure that the parentheses are matched (i.e. both parentheses are present, or both parentheses are missing).

[Demo (using Java regex engine)](http://ideone.com/xuKbHW).

Comment: You don't need to double backslashes inside `r'...'` strings (this looks like Python).

Comment: How are you planning to parse sinhx?

Comment: @AndrewFount Is `sinhx` even supposed to be valid without a space? If I were an end-user, the fact that this even parses would be extremely confusing to me.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes. And can you answer is there any difference between `([h]?) and (h?) and (h)?` ? You also used either \( or [(]

Comment: Apparently the original allows `sinxyz` and `sinhxyz`, which should parse as `sin(xyz)` and `sinh(xyz)`.

Comment: I think a negative lookahead is probably the right solution, but it's something I'm still shaky on and I've been having trouble coming up with the right RE, so I haven't been able to post it as an answer.

Comment: @AndrewFount Did you try the simple but lengthy `sin|cos|tan|cot|sec|csc|sinh|cosh|tanh|coth|sech|csch`? As far as `(h)?` vs. `([h]?)` vs. `(h?)` goes, there is no difference: the engine produces a single capturing group that matches an optional `h` in all situations. I prefer square brackets in Java, because it looks better without a double backslash. In languages where double backslash is not required, there is no reason to use square brackets.

Comment: That doesn't fix it: https://regex101.com/r/zX1yI3/1. It still backtracks and chooses `sin` as the match for the first group, and treats `h` as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a pretty robust way to parse the input into (function) (possible ^2) (parameter)

```
(sinh?|cosh?|tan|cot|sec|csc)[ (]*([\^a-z0-9]*?) *([a-z0-9]+)\)?$
```

simpler & more concise that using look-ahead methods perhaps.